# Is battery protection mode still active when the device is off?

Tags: charging, battery-life, tablet, lenovo, battery-saver

I have a lenovo tablet that has a charging dock that it's left in 24/7 (or at least almost 24/7) I have turned on battery protection mode to preserve it's longevity, but I am unsure whether the device will continue to charge past the 60% threshold when the device is off. Does anyone know if battery protection mode stays active?

Comment: My Lenovo tablet only applies the charging limit if the device is on. Charging in off state ignores everything configured and always charges to 100%.

Comment: [protection mode works only when device is powered on for this Lenovo device](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Android-based-Tablets-and-Phablets/M8-FHD-battery-protection-mode-question/m-p/5071354)//Maybe same for your device//you can test it